# Laravel. Routes do not match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5, web-frameworks

At first it seems that the same routes. But in first route not working middleware that I ordered in the constructor.

How to fix that?

```
Route::get('/cars.get', function() {

return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\CarsController')->{'get'}();

});

Route::get('/cars.get', 'CarsController@get');
```

*sorry for my English =)*

Comment: `Route::get('cars.get')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

I was wrong about `callAction()` it does nothing else than call the method.
Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a simple API to call middleware manually. A solution to this would just be to define the middleware on the route:

```
Route::get('/cars.get', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\CarsController')->{'get'}();
}]);
```

*original answer:*

By directly calling the `get()` method you skip middleware defined in the controller. You should use `callAction()` instead:

```
return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\CarsController')->callAction('get');
```

---

Also note that you can use `app()` as a shortcut for `App::make()`:

```
return app('App\Http\Controllers\CarsController')->callAction('get');
```

Comment: Middleware still not working now.

I think I must call middleware manually before controller is executed, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Right... Now that I look at the source I realize that it does just call the method (that was different in Laravel 4). Also I can't really find any method to call it including the middleware or calling the middleware manually. Would specifying the middleware in the route itself be an option for you?

Comment: if i will not find solution how to calling middleware manually, i will use second variant. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you find something :) (btw I've updated the answer so it's clear for others without reading the comments)